# Simulating single action in parallel with recurring actions in Jmeter

Tags: concurrency, jmeter

Suppose I've 50 users. I want the load of 49 users on the website in parallel with 50th user who will be performing a time-consuming single action only once. How can I achieve such concurrency in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be using different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent different business groups of virtual users so you can have:

1. 1 Thread Group of 49 users doing the browsing or whatever
2. 1 Thread Group of 1 user doing a time-consuming single action

Alternatively you can go for a single Thread Group of 50 users and use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to limit execution of the single action to 1:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)